# Laravel 5 windows server, mysql 500 error, goes blank

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache, webserver

> Problem 1 is why my all of 2 projects goes blank? and when  i see my console it says 500 error. and network was blank.
>
> Problem 2 is my logs error.

Laravel 5 My 2 projects is running on

```
Operating system is :Windows server, 
Web server:  Apache 2.4.33
Web framework: Laravel
Php version 7.1.16
```

and problem is it goes blank once or twice on day. No error message no screen just white blank. And I tried to see it from `storage/logs/laravel.log` it says.

```
No application encryption key has been specified
```

But i already have

```
APP_KEY=base64:6li20zwKAcVdNmcaHY06ZEbzHecfQasnCP+wv1L3R6o=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `php artiasn key:generate` for generate new key